# How do I view headers in Yahoo Mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I am looking to view headers but I see no option

Where is that option?

[image: "More" menu]

Comment: @pnuts nothing there suits. And I know you don't use yahoo mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "More" menu shows that sometimes when you're looking at a list of email. There's a bug in Yahoo Mail whether it shows that menu or the fuller one, when viewing a list of email. I find that if I click the first email then click inbox to see the list of email. Then it shows the limited menu you show there. But if I click any other email then click inbox, then it shows the fuller menu.  But if you want to see the header of an email, there's no point being in inbox view.

Two things to try, to get the full menu

**First thing to try**

Open an email then the more menu should show this, and if not then test with  opening a few different emails see if yahoo have a bug there too, but for me when viewing an email I always got the fuller menu.

[image: Menu screen shot]

**Second thing to try**

The first thing to try, doesn't seem to work for emails that are in threads (or at least not the one I'm currently looking at). But there is another more option at the bottom:

[image: "More" menu from threaded view]